# Kubernetes flask request configmap data

Tags: python, flask, kubernetes, configmap, argo-workflows

I have flask application on kubernetes cluster. In the same namespace configmap deployed with multiple key-value pairs. Is there a way from flask to request(reqeuests configmap cluster API?) data of that config map inside cluster without creating deployment and service?

Comment: How is your Flask application deployed on the K8s cluster? There is a [kubernetes-client Python API](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python), so it's possible for an app to make requests just like how you would use the `kubectl` CLI... but if your Flask app is already deployed, why not just mount the configmap onto the same deployment? Please [edit] to show the configmap and what _exactly_ do you want to get from it?

Comment: please share your yaml manifest...

Comment: I've decided in the end to make manifest of config yaml published to web and fetch it from flask application. Problem was, I could mount configmap, but couldn't iterate through all key value pairs(couldn't find a way). Ty for your ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Just mount the configmap datas in your flask deployment.

You can do so by either mount datas in environment variables OR into files directly

Cf: https://kubernetes.io/fr/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/